# Do break down vs break up (meaning "to divide" something) have the same usage?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

According to the Cambridge dictionary (image below), the phrasal verbs ["break down"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break-down) and ["break up"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break-up) share the same meaning, "to divide".

Moreover, according to [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/210827/142725) apparently there's a difference between these two phrasal verbs, but I'm not sure if that answer is correct.

Can someone explain if there is a difference between these two phrasal verbs?

[image: Break down meaning]
[image: Break up meaning]

Comment: The usage is not the same.

Comment: The overlap does not make them identical. If you break down on a trip, you had a flat tire or emotional meltdown rather than introducing a visit to Singapore. There's the down compared to up element.

Comment: @YosefBaskin so, If I said, "we are breaking down our trip...", it means that we have a flat tire or emotional meltdown?

Comment: Not my point. Breaking down a trip could mean explaining it to someone, dividing it metaphorically for details. But not for a stop in Singapore.

Comment: @YosefBaskin so, the sentence "we are breaking down our trip by stopping for a few days in Singapore" does not make sense?

Comment: Both expressions have connotations in specific contexts that are often different and even contradictory.

Comment: @HotLicks can you elaborate more please?

Comment: @Marlonchosky - Well, I might "break down" a shipping crate so that I can store the pieces compactly for later use.  Or I might "break up" the crate to use it as firewood.

Comment: If I break down something, I separate it into its component parts. If something (a car, say) breaks down, it fails to function properly. If Don and Sue break up, they’re ending their romance. Just a few examples.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207959/break-up-vs-breakup-vs-break-down

Answer (score 2):

There are many uses of both "break down" and "break up" which are not described by the shared definition "to divide". Examples, two of which have already been given in comments, are: a vehicle breaking down (which was used in this sense before the internal combustion engine existed), breaking down emotionally or psychologically and breaking up romantically.

The difference between the two phrases when they both mean "to divide" is usually the difference between a careful or analytical approach and a rougher action which tends to leave physical divided parts broken and not reusable.

For example if a task is broken down there is an analytical process undertaken where the sub-tasks are carefully defined, The description "breaking up the task" would not, normally, be used. Similarly if a machine is "broken down for cleaning" it is carefully separated into its component parts and the parts are treated carefully so that the machine can be reassembled.

On the other hand if an old ship is "broken up for scrap" most of it is cut up into fairly random pieces which are of value only because they can be melted down, not reassembled into an identical new ship. Specific components such as the engine, the galley and even the toilets may be recovered but most of the ship disappears. The same thing applies to breaking up a crate for firewood or breaking down a crate for storage. The latter is a more careful process leaving reusable components.

There are cases where the distinction is less rigid. For example the case of a corporation being "broken up" where most of the component parts are sold as functioning units but even there the corporation cannot be reassembled in its previous form and parts of it, such as the corporate headquarters organisation disappear completely. I suggest that this process is closer to breaking up a ship than to breaking down a machine.

There may well be cases where this distinction does not apply but as a general rule it does.

Comment: I knew that both "break down" and "break up" have other meanings besides "to divide", and that was no mention in my question because I only tried to focus on the meaning of "to divide something".
Now with your answer it is not yet clear to me if there's a difference between these two phrasal verbs. For instance, in the example provided by Cambridge: "We're breaking up our trip by stopping for a few days in Sangapore." Can I replace break up to break down in that sentence?

Comment: I wouldn't use either "break up" or "break down" to refer to a stop over in the middle of a journey. I would just say that I "broke" the journey. The reason is that the journey is still a single entity with a pause and neither of the parts can be worked on or used separately. No native speaker I know would talk about "breaking up" (or breaking down) a journey unless they were going to do different things on each stage, and even then it would be really rare.

Answer (score 0):

In common use *breaking down* can be breaking down a description, a detailed explanation of the trip, the itinerary and schedule into its details. It can also mean the car breaking down on the trip, that is malfunctioning, or just breaking. *Breaking up* will likely refer to the end of the relationship of the people on the trip. They have a relationship that breaks up due to the stresses of the trip, likely brought on by the breaking down of the vehicle.